# invariant subspace partition

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory

-rudin-2th.pdf">http://59clc.files.wordpress.com/2012/08/functional-analysis--rudin-2th.pdf

on page 327 Rudin says that M and M' are invariant subspaces. I'm guessing he means non-trivial so how does he know of the existence of  a partition w and w' such that both E(w) and E(w') are not the zero map and not surjective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no indication that $M$ and $M'$ are supposed nontrivial invariant subspaces. But by part $(d)$ if theorem 12.22,

> If $\omega \subset \Delta$ is open and nonempty, then $E(\omega) \neq 0$

and the monotonicity, whenever the spectrum contains more than one point, there are partitions of $\Delta$ into disjoint Borel sets $\omega$ and $\omega'$ such that $E(\omega)\neq 0\neq E(\omega')$.

If $x,y \in \Delta$ with $x\neq y$, let $r = \frac12 \lvert x-y\rvert$, and set $\omega = \Delta \cap B_r(x)$, $\omega' = \Delta \setminus \omega$. Both are Borel sets with nonempty interior (relative to $\Delta$), hence the associated projections are nonzero.

Comment: How do you know their interior is non-empty and what if the projections are surjective, then their ranges are the whole space @Daniel Fischer

Comment: $\omega$ is by definition open in $\Delta$, as it is the intersection of $\Delta$ with the open ball of radius $r$ and centre $x$. Since it contains $x$, it is not empty, hence per 12.22 $(d)$, we have $E(\omega) \neq 0$. $\omega'$ contains the (intersection of $\Delta$ with the) open ball of radius $r$ with centre $y$, so it contains a nonempty open set, and by monotonicity $E(\omega') \geqslant E(\Delta\cap B_r(y)) \neq 0$.

Comment: thanks. I think the surjective issue is sorted out thus. The direct sum of the ranges is H, Both are non-zero so if one was all of H there would be a contradiction with their zero intersection. @DanielFischer